# Can't set up a spy on $A.enqueueAction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unit-test

I'm following the guidelines on setting up unit tests for my Aura component. However, I am having difficulty spying on, and setting up a callFake function on the $A.enqueueAction method in order to stub the server response.

Normally, of course, I would use Jasmine's `spyOn` method, but to simplify my debugging, I directly assigned a new function to `$A.enqueueAction` in my test class:

```
// test code
$A.enqueueAction = function(action) {
    console.log('fake $A.enqueueAction method');
}
```

And reduced the controller code so that it just calls the `$A.enqueueAction` method:

```
// controller code
console.log($A.enqueueAction);
$A.enqueueAction({});
```

I can see by logging out the `$A.enqueueAction` method in the controller that it is the usual full version, and not the fake function assigned in the unit test setup.

This makes me think that the `$A` object in the controller and the `$A` object in the test setup are different objects.

It is strange that I am able to stub the server calls correctly using `spyOn($A, 'enqueueAction')` in my other test files. Can anyone think of a reason why this could be happening for this one?